# SonarQube with C# plugin with MSBuild Runner takes a lot of time

Tags: c#, msbuild, sonarqube, metrics

Currently I have an instance of SonarQube 5.1.2 with C# plugin and MSBuild runner in order to analyze a 1.200.000 LOC project, the analysis is taking between 16 and 20 hours. Digging into the logs, the building process (including the execution of test) takes about 2 hours, starting from there, SonarQube start its analysis.

SonarQube is setup as it comes out of the box, it is installed in a machine with 8Gb in RAM, 4 processors. Usually, the analysis process only uses 20% of the CPU and 1.5 GB of RAM.

What actions should I take to reduce the analysis time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Upgrade to the latest release version of SonarQube. Before SonarQube 5.2, a database connection was established from the analysis machine to the database, and there were **a lot of round-trips** to upload the analysis results.

Since 5.2, the analysis machine zips the analysis results and sends it to the server, which will process it and store it in the database in a much more optimized way.

Also feel free to investigate and report what the bottleneck is once you're on the latest released versions and if you still face performance issues.

Comment: We tried to upgrade to 5.2, but the analysis didn't finish, so it was a worst situation that the one described above

Comment: Can you attach the build logs? where does it get stuck? Without more details it'll be impossible to find the root cause of the issue and fix it on our side

Comment: I can attach the logs for the current setup, not for the one with 5.2 due we already rollback

Comment: yes go ahead with the current logs, perhaps it'll be obvious: make sure to include some timestamps to see where the analysis is spending its time

Comment: I made an upgrade inside an experimental machine, to SonarQube 5.3, it reduces time from 16 hours to 5 hours

Comment: sounds much better. If you do import code coverage, and have huge reports and/or hundreds of projects in your solution, you might also be facing this performance issue: https://jira.sonarsource.com/browse/SONARNTEST-29 - The fix for that problem is not yet released, even though the current version under development already has it